# How to code VBA Vlookup that includes cell formatting from the source cell?

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, vlookup

I'm looking for a way to keep the source formatting from the cells that I perform a vlookup on with the following function:

```
On Error Resume Next
With aSheet
    For i = FindEmptyRow To FindRow2
        .Range("N" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Range("A" & i), Sheets("data_temp").Range("A:W"), 14, False)
        .Range("O" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Range("A" & i), Sheets("data_temp").Range("A:W"), 15, False)
        .Range("P" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Range("A" & i), Sheets("data_temp").Range("A:W"), 16, False)
        .Range("Q" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Range("A" & i), Sheets("data_temp").Range("A:W"), 17, False)
        .Range("R" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Range("A" & i), Sheets("data_temp").Range("A:W"), 18, False)
        .Range("S" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Range("A" & i), Sheets("data_temp").Range("A:W"), 19, False)
        .Range("T" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Range("A" & i), Sheets("data_temp").Range("A:W"), 20, False)
        .Range("U" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Range("A" & i), Sheets("data_temp").Range("A:W"), 21, False)
        .Range("V" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Range("A" & i), Sheets("data_temp").Range("A:W"), 22, False)
        .Range("W" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Range("A" & i), Sheets("data_temp").Range("A:W"), 23, False)
    Next i
End With
```

I see that other people are struggling with this specific issue as well, but I haven't been able to find an answer that solved my issue.

Is there any way that I can use the PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats- to preserve the cell format?

I tried looking at storing the vlookup formula as a string and pasting that directly into each cell, but couldn't quite get my head around how that would work inside a loop.

Is there formula other than VLOOKUP that's better suited for this particular issue?

Please let me know, if you need further backstory to the issue or more code.

Hoping somebody will be able to help me out!

Best regards,
Magnus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses MATCH to find the correct row, then it copies and pastes the cells.

```
With aSheet
    Dim mtchrw As Long
    
    For i = FindEmptyRow To FindRow2
        mtchrw = 0
        On Error Resume Next
            mtchrw = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(.Range("A" & i), Sheets("data_temp").Range("A:A"), 0)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If mtchrw > 0 then
            Sheets("data_temp").Range("N" & mtchrw & ":W" & mtchrw).Copy .Range("N" & I & ":W" & i)
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Hi Scott,
Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately the MATCH function doesn't do the trick, as the order of the rows in the first column doesn't necessarily correspond to number and order of rows in the lookup table. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Thank you, Scott! Working perfectly now :) Much obliged.

Comment: @MagnusCarstens please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.